# How can players with 10 victories be level 25 in League of Legends?

Tags: league-of-legends

I noticed some players with very few wins but their level is about 25. How is this possible? Do they play with bots? Or do they really almost never win? Or do they play incredibly well?

Comment: Could be a very old account that reached lvl 25 or so from way before season 1, from before they started to count the wins and such.

Comment: @Lyrion games wins are not erased after a new season. At least not for unranked games (don't remember about ranked ones). Being lvl 25 he hasn't access to ranked games, so even if the account was created during season 1, games won in season 1 are still counted here.

Comment: @soenguy He said **before** season 1 - when they were actually not counting wins

Comment: ARAM? Aren't those counted differently from regular wins?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Lets look at what is required to get to level 25+

[image: League of Legends XP]

[Chart Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_%28summoner%29)

The received Experience Points are calculated at the end of each game; wins are worth more than losses, and the longer the game lasts, the more XP you gain.

Assuming an average XP gain to be about 110 XP per normal game, one can reach summoner level 25 within 246 normal games. Using XP boosts will double the amount of XP you recieve. So, lets assume someone got the maximum XP which for winning a normal game will be around 200 + the use of XP boosts = 400 xp per win. One can get to 25 in 68 games.
[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Experience_%28summoner%29)

However, it is important to note that depending on where you are looking will depend on what information is shown to you. For example, if you are seeing the 10 wins from a summoner at the end of a normal game then it will only show the stats from winning normals. This means it won't show any stats for winning any other mode (Dominion, ARAM, CO-OP vs AI, custom games).

It is quite possible that someone could reach 25 through playing only Dominion, ARAM etc games and has only played around 20 games of normal. For you to get a real idea of how many games someone has played I would recommend using [lolking.net](http://www.lolking.net/). It should show all the games someone has played in which mode, their wins, losses and many other statistics.

Answer (score 5):

There are basically two ways to achieve this:

The first would be by just playing other Queues than normal 5v5. Other Game queues aren't listed as "wins" and thus the low amount of won games in normals.

The second method is rather weird and requires him to really be losing all the time. This would require a incredible high amount of games for him to lose which is highly unlikely to happen.

Either way there is no "hacking" or "exploiting" involved.

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much answered your own question.

They could be playing with bots, losing a lot, or perhaps even using experience boosts.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the Wiki :

> There is both a minimum and a maximum amount of XP and IP a player can
>   get from a game. Current (July 2011) formula for XP winning a Normal
>   game at level 15-19 is roughly 3m+25, where m is the number of minutes
>   the game lasts, capped at 198. Intermediate Bot games at level 10-14
>   use the same formula. At level 15-19, Intermediate Bot games subtract
>   a 25% penalty from that formula, and give XP for only the first 180
>   minutes a day of play.

Also, from the table on that article, Level 25 can be reached from 27020 Cumulative EXP.

Even with an XP Boost and the cap, it will take around 60+ games before you reach the needed XP.

Maybe you're only looking at the Summoner's Rift stats. Try looking at his stats on other games ( Twisted Treeline, Dominion )

Answer (score 1):

The wins that appears on the screen only counts the normal game (or ranked wins if you already played a few). I know people that has 3 wins being lvl 30. They only play vs AI so its possible to achieve a lvl 30 account without a single normal game win

Answer (score 1):

Bots, ARAM, Dominion, other special modes (URF, Doom Bots, etc) and Team Builder (This one they are working on including it in the future). All give XP but do not count as normal games.

Comment: Last time I checked Dominion wins do reflect as Wins. At least mine goes up after each Dominion victory...ARAMs, Customs, and Coop-vs-AI are the only ones to my knowledge that don't reflect.

Comment: @Shelby115 It depends where you are looking. If the OP got his information by hovering over the player at the end of a normal game, it would only show normal wins.

Comment: I seem to recall some patch note mentioning that Team Builder wins are added to both Team Builder wins and Normal wins... I'll see if I can dig up a source.